# VLOOKUP() is getting an error when trying to get values from another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have some data organized like this in a spreadsheet

```
c1          c2              c3          c4      c5      c6      c7   c8     c9
3137EACY3   FHLMC 0.75 14   11/25/14    Q414    -3.5    -3.5    2YR -13.6   0.26
3135G0HG1   FNMA 0.375 15   03/16/15    Q115    2.4     2.4     2YR -11.4   0.32
3135G0KM4   FNMA 0.5 15     05/27/15    Q215    3.5     3.5     2YR -13     0.33
31359MZC0   FNMA 4.375 15   10/15/15    Q315    13.1    13.1    2YR -9.9    0.43
31359MH89   FNMA 5 16       03/15/16    Q415    5.7     5.7     3YR -5.7    0.55
3137EADQ9   FHLMC 0.5 16    05/13/16    Q116    1       1       3YR -14.5   0.5
3135G0XP3   FNMA 0.375 16   07/05/16    Q216    10.7    10.7    3YR -8.6    0.6
31359M2D4   FNMA 4.875 16   12/15/16    Q316    21.4    21.4    3YR -9      0.71
3137EADC0   FHLMC 1 17      03/08/17    Q416    31.5    31.5    3YR -5.9    0.81
3137EADF3   FHLMC 1.25 17   05/12/17    Q117    -14.6   -14.6   5YR -5.5    0.86
3137EAAY5   FHLMC 5.5 17    08/23/17    Q217    -10.5   -10.5   5YR -7.3    0.9
3135G0RT2   FNMA 0.875 17   12/20/17    Q317    7       7       5YR -1.5    1.08
3137EADP1   FHLMC 0.875 18  03/07/18    Q417    13.1    13.1    5YR -1.3    1.14
3137EABP3   FHLMC 4.875 18  06/13/18    Q118    8.8     8.8     5YR -10     1.09
3137EACA5   FHLMC 3.75 19   03/27/19    Q218    39.4    39.4    5YR -0.7    1.4
```

And in another spreadsheet, I have some data organized like this:

```
i1          i2                      i3          i4
EG8566960   EIB 4.75 10/15/14       10/15/14    Q414
500769AX2   KFW 4.125 10/15/14      10/15/14    Q414
045167BJ1   ASIA 4.25 10/20/14      10/20/14    Q414
298785FT8   EIB 0.875 12/15/14      12/15/14    Q414
500769ET7   KFW 1 01/12/15          01/12/15    Q115
EI1571062   CADES 2.875 03/02/15    03/02/15    Q115
XS0213706   EUROF 4.5               03/06/15    Q115
676167AQ2   OKB 4.5                 03/09/15    Q115
XS0495091   NEDWBK 3                03/17/15    Q115
```

I'd like to write a `VLOOKUP()` that gets the value of c6 when i4 and c4 match up, but I'm having some trouble and can't figure out why I'm getting a #N/A error.  Here's what I have written in my vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(D7,'Sheet2'!A:I, 7, FALSE)
```

Where D7 is where `Q414` lies in my first spreadsheet.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I'm getting this error?  I feel like I've tried just about anything I can find online.  When I look at the calculation steps, it goes from:

```
VLOOKUP("Q414",'Sheet2'!A:I,7,FALSE)
```

with the entire function underlined to:

```
#N/A
```

So I know that it is properly selecting "Q414" at least...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You select the table_array from the column containing the value you're looking for, in your case:

```
=VLOOKUP(D7,'Sheet2'!G:I, 3, FALSE)
```

`G` is the column where the `Q414` is found, hence why the table array starts at `G`. And relative to this column is column `I`, the third column after `G`.

Note that vlookup only return the first match, but I'm not sure what you're exactly doing, so :)

EDIT: There was a little misunderstanding and columns c4 and c6 were actually in column D and F respectively. The formula as barry houdini rightly pointed out is thus:

```
=VLOOKUP(D7,'Sheet2'!D:F,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: I am trying to select the values into a column `i5` for each row in the second spreadsheet I showed, which is actually my `Sheet1`

Comment: @weskpga Yes, I know this. What made me say the last line was that there were a lot of `Q414` in Sheet1. That said, the formula should work. Did you get the chance to test it?

Comment: @weskpga Oops! I counted wrong! It should be `3` instead of `2` above. I edited my anwer.

Comment: Jerry's approach looks right to me - which column is "c4"? Assuming you mean column D (and "c6" is column F) then I assume you want `=VLOOKUP(D7,'Sheet2'!D:F,3,FALSE)`

Comment: @barryhoudini or perhaps we are dealing with hidden columns, which would explain quite some things...

Comment: @barryhoudini - Yes, you are correct.  That worked!  Finally haha